# How do I get a Named Pipe to block in C#?

Tags: c#, windows, named-pipes

I'm writing a C# Windows Service (**server**) that will need to receive messages from C++ GUI applications (**clients**) using a *Named Pipe* very infrequently; it could be days to weeks before a message is received. In my testing I noticed that instead of blocking for data to come in, it just continually checks and prints newlines. It does receive the test message but I had to use the debugger in Visual Studio to verify.

Is there a way to get the C# portion to block until there is actually data to be received?

--C# Code:

```
    var client = new NamedPipeServerStream("PipeTest");
    client.WaitForConnection();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(client);

    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadLine());
    }
```

--C++ Code:

```
    DWORD written;
    INT error_code;
    CHAR buffer[1024];
    LPCWSTR pipe_name = L"\\\\.\\pipe\\PipeTest";
    LRESULT result;

    WaitNamedPipe(pipe_name, NMPWAIT_WAIT_FOREVER);
    HANDLE hpipe = CreateFile(pipe_name,
                              GENERIC_WRITE,
                              0,
                              NULL, 
                              OPEN_EXISTING,
                              FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                              NULL);

    error_code = GetLastError();
    sprintf_s(buffer,"Sending Test Message");
    WriteFile(hpipe,buffer,strlen(buffer),&written,NULL);
    result = GetLastError();
    fprintf(stdout,"Pipe: %d Write: %d Written: %d",error_code,result,written);
    DisconnectNamedPipe(hpipe);
    CloseHandle(hpipe);
    std::cin.get();
```

***[ANSWER]***

--C# Code(***server***) with corrected names:

```
   var server = new NamedPipeServerStream("PipeTest");
   while (true)
   {
        server.WaitForConnection();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(server);
        Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadLine());
        server.Disconnect();
   }
```

For this code I'll only need to capture one line worth of data, @The Shooter was correct but you'll need to add `server.Disconnect()` in order to read again. I found this from the C [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365166(v=vs.85).aspx) and the same principle works in C# apparently.

> The server process must call `DisconnectNamedPipe` to disconnect a pipe handle from its previous client before the handle can be connected to another client by using the `ConnectNamedPipe` function.

Comment: By default, reading from a named pipe _will_ block. If you see repeated newlines reading from your pipe, then that's what's being sent. Please provide a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem.

Comment: @Peter Duniho "Please provide a good Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example that reliably reproduces the problem", am I supposed to include all the `#includes` and `using System..` as well, I was trying to keep this as short as possible?

Comment: Leaving out some boilerplate is fine. But neither of the code segments you provided are even complete programs. It's not at all clear from your question that the behavior you describe occurs _after_ the remote endpoint closes the pipe, especially since your C# code waits for the connection only once. When you provide complete programs and precise details as to exactly how they are used, the question is much clearer and more likely to elicit useful answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The client end is disconnecting the pipe, so the server sees the end of the input stream immediately after the test message is received.

The documentation for [StreamReader.ReadLine()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline(v=vs.110).aspx) says:

> The next line from the input stream, or null if the end of the input stream is reached.

So `ReadLine` is returning `null`; what does [Console.WriteLine(String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xf2k8ftb(v=vs.110).aspx) do in that case?

> If value is null, only the line terminator is written to the standard output stream.

QED.  The behaviour you're seeing is exactly as expected.

You need to check the value returned from `ReadLine` and deal with `null` appropriately.  In this case you presumably want to wait for another connection.

Comment: That makes more sense, I was assuming that `StreamReader.Readline()` would block since there wouldn't be anything to read. Would there be a better way to write this? This will be going on critical systems and I don't really want it to be polling the entire time.

Comment: @pixel: _"This will be going on critical systems"_ -- frankly, a critical system is not the place for a person brand new to inter-process communications to be cutting their teeth. You need to at least find someone experienced on your team who can advise you, because even if you get this part working, you're likely to inject other subtle errors in the code as well.

Comment: There's no need to poll.  Waiting for a connection is a blocking call.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
var client = new NamedPipeServerStream("PipeTest");
client.WaitForConnection();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(client);

while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadLine());
}
```

Try this:

```
var client = new NamedPipeServerStream("PipeTest");
while (true)
{
    client.WaitForConnection();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(client);
    Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadLine());
}
```

Comment: This won't work if the client sends more than one line.